Docker Django application deployment
I have a Django app that I am trying to 'Dockerize'.
Here is the Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10.12-slim-bullseye                    
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1                    
ENV PORT 8080                          
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/                           
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt    

CMD gunicorn django_ec2_complete.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:"${PORT}"

EXPOSE ${PORT}    

I am following some tutorials and docs and there are for sure mistakes or something I am missing.
I can run the following docker build command successfully:
docker build -t django-ec2-complete:latest .
But, when trying to docker run:
docker run -p 8000:8080 django-ec2-complete:latest
I get the following Traceback error:
[2024-06-03 17:00:52 +0000] [7] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 22.0.0
[2024-06-03 17:00:52 +0000] [7] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (7)
[2024-06-03 17:00:52 +0000] [7] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2024-06-03 17:00:52 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
[2024-06-03 17:00:52 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_ec2_complete'
[2024-06-03 17:00:52 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
[2024-06-03 17:00:52 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Worker (pid:8) exited with code 3
[2024-06-03 17:00:52 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
[2024-06-03 17:00:52 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Tried to make sense of the Traceback error and right now I am stuck.
Thank you in advance.

Are you just copying lines from somewhere randomly? This dockerfile presumes that there is a file django_ec2_complete/wsgi.py in CWD (so /app/django_ec2_complete/wsgi.py). Add your directory tree to the question. And this Dockerfile is terribly inefficient: you will reinstall all dependencies on every rebuild instead of leveraging docker's layer cache. The usual flow is COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt (consider usig some fancier package manager also), then RUN pip install -r requirements.txt, and only then COPY . /app.

I am completely new to Docker and just following along with some tutorials. Thank you for reply, will spend some more time debugging it.

Where is your wsgi.py located? Pick it's parent folder and use that name instead of django_ec2_complete.

Used the folder where wsgi.py is located and the docker build command worked perfectly.
Do you have any idea why the CSS file results as Not found?
Thank you for your help.

That is a different question about different problem, and your dockerfile is likely irrelevant to it. You will need to explain how you serve those static files: assuming that you're using built-in Django mechanisms, your root urls.py and settings.py will be most important along with an example of a template where this static file is requested. Make sure to remove all unnecessary details (don't post 400 lines of HTML code to show the {% static %} reference in one of them) and mask/remove all secrets in settings shall you have any. Also check that your question wasn't asked here before.
